# Move_uploaded_file having issues with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to add a file upload to WordPress, all is working well so far except for move_uploaded_file.

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment">
```

The field in my form above

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"],WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/cv/'.basename($_FILES['attachment']['name'])))
        {
            $return['error'] = true; $return['error_message'] = __('File could not be uploaded', 'btoa').'<br />';

        }
```

Attempting to move the uploaded file, it's not working and displaying the error.

I've tried to use is_uploaded_file, which also returns false, the uploads folder is 777, the folder it is trying to save in /cv/ is also 777.

I am not quite sure what is going wrong here, there is no error log being created and I just can't seem to get it to work.

Apart from moving the uploaded file, sending out attachments is working perfectly.

Anything I can do?

FORM CODE

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url() ?>" method="post" id="enquiry-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p><small class="error" style="margin-top: 15px; display: none;"></small></p>

            <p><input type="text" value="<?php _e('Your name', 'btoa'); ?>" name="name" id="enquiry-name" onfocus="if(jQuery(this).val() == '<?php _e('Your name', 'btoa'); ?>') { jQuery(this).val(''); }" onblur="if(jQuery(this).val() == '') { jQuery(this).val('<?php _e('Your name', 'btoa'); ?>'); }" /></p>

            <p><input type="text" value="<?php _e('Email address', 'btoa'); ?>" name="email" id="enquiry-email" onfocus="if(jQuery(this).val() == '<?php _e('Email address', 'btoa'); ?>') { jQuery(this).val(''); }" onblur="if(jQuery(this).val() == '') { jQuery(this).val('<?php _e('Email address', 'btoa'); ?>'); }" /></p>
            <p><label for="file">Upload your CV/Resume:</label></p>
            <p style="margin-bottom:0;"><input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment"></p>

            <p><textarea name="message" id="enquiry-message" cols="" rows="4" onfocus="if(jQuery(this).val() == '<?php _e('Message', 'btoa'); ?>') { jQuery(this).val(''); }" onblur="if(jQuery(this).val() == '') { jQuery(this).val('<?php _e('Message', 'btoa'); ?>'); }"><?php _e('Message', 'btoa'); ?></textarea></p>

            <p><input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Send', 'btoa'); ?>" /></p>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!-- /.clear/ -->

            <div class="error-message"></div>

            <div class="thank-you hidden">

                <p><?php _e('Thank you! Your message has been successfully sent.', 'btoa'); ?></p>

            </div>

        </form>
```

SUCCESS FORM CODE

```
//// IF EMAIL IS VALID
    if($return['error'] == '') {

        /// GETS OTHER VARS
        $name = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : '';
        $the_message = isset($_POST['message']) ? trim($_POST['message']) : '';
        $post_id = isset($_POST['post_id']) ? trim($_POST['post_id']) : '';

        //// NOW WE GET OUR SPOT AND THE USER
        $spot = get_post($post_id);
        $user = get_user_by('id', $spot->post_author);

        //// STARTS OUR RECIPIENT ARRAY
        $to = $user->user_email;

        //// HEADERS
        $headers = 'From: '.get_bloginfo('name').' <'.get_option('admin_email').'>'."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email;

        $subject = sprintf2(__('%site_name Contact: %spot_name', 'btoa'), array('site_name' => get_bloginfo('name'), 'spot_name' => $spot->post_title));
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"],WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/cv/'.basename($_FILES['attachment']['name'])))
        {
            $return['error'] = true; $return['error_message'] = __('File could not be uploaded', 'btoa').'<br />';
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

        }


$attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/uploads/cv/".basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']));
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'my_custom_email_content_type' );
        function my_custom_email_content_type() {
return 'text/html';
}
        $message = sprintf2(__("Dear %author,

%user (email: %email) has sent you a message via %site_name:

-----

%message", 'btoa'), array(

            'author' => $user->display_name,
            'user' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'site_name' => get_bloginfo('name'),
            'attachment' => $attachments,
            'message' => $the_message

        ));



        //// SENDS OUT OUR EMAIL
        if(!wp_mail($to, $subject, stripslashes($message), $headers, $attachments)) {

            $return['error'] = true; $return['error_email'] = sprintf2(__('There was a problem sending your enquiry. Please email us directly at %site_email', 'btoa'), array('site_email' => get_option('admin_email')));

        } else { $return['success'] = stripslashes($headers); }

    }

    echo json_encode($return);
    exit;

}
```

Ignore the slightly messy code while trying to fix this bug.

Also attempted to add/adjust this in wp_config, but still no error logs being created in root or wp-content

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: Add this `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);` then you get an error log

Comment: Thanks, done that but still no error_log created so I am not sure how to debug this, will be editing to poste more complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried echoing out the WP_CONTENT_DIR and seeing what that gets? Or doing a `var_dump(is_dir(WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/cv/'.basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']))`. Also doing a print_r on the $_FILES array to see the actual error number it returns and correlating that with: https://www.php.net//manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php may help. Let me know the results to each please unless of course you figure it out.